# error: Could not find the AndroidManifest.xml file in specified path

Tags: android, android-studio

I am in the middle of upgrading my Android from the API version 23-26. So far so good, just the last bit I encountered this error as below.

> error: Could not find the AndroidManifest.xml file in specified path

I am suspecting it was due to the latest version of the Gradle or the Android plug-in. Any hints or ideas?

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'


repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}
android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    flavorDimensions "default"
   // buildToolsVersion "26.0.0"
    defaultConfig {

        javaCompileOptions {
            annotationProcessorOptions {
                arguments = [
                        'androidManifestFile': 'app\\build\\intermediates\\merged_manifests\\debug\\processDebugManifest\\merged\\AndroidManifest.xml'
                ]
            }
        }
        applicationId "jp.co.mindpiece"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
dependencies {

    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestImplementation('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'

    implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
    implementation files('libs/YouTubeAndroidPlayerApi.jar')

    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.0.0'

    annotationProcessor 'org.androidannotations:androidannotations:4.0.0'
    implementation 'org.androidannotations:androidannotations-api:4.0.0'
    implementation 'com.nostra13.universalimageloader:universal-image-loader:1.9.5'
    implementation 'com.squareup.sqlbrite:sqlbrite:0.5.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    implementation 'com.j256.ormlite:ormlite-android:4.48'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.4'
    implementation 'com.google.guava:guava:20.0'
    implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:10.2.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:10.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.0.1'
    implementation('com.twitter.sdk.android:twitter:2.2.0@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
    //implementation project(':android-pdf-viewer')
    implementation 'com.github.barteksc:android-pdf-viewer:3.1.0-beta.1'
    implementation project(':coverflow')
    implementation 'org.lucasr.twowayview:twowayview:0.1.4'
}
```

Comment: May I know what is missing here?

Comment: were you able to resolve this problem? If yes then how if you can share your experience would be a great help! thanks